# Sqlite triggered update malfunctions

Tags: android, database, sqlite, triggers

I have a table which needs to be triggered upon insert into one of the tables. I have written 2 triggers but the values in the desired table aren't getting updated as expected. On the contrary, it is the same value being entered in both the column.

```
const val NEW_TRANSACTION_TRIGGER_NAME = "transaction_insert_trigger"
const val NEW_TRANSACTION_TRIGGER = "create trigger $NEW_TRANSACTION_TRIGGER_NAME " +
    "after insert on transactions " +
    "begin " +
    "update transactions " +
    "set firm_id = (select firm_id from parties where id = new.party_id) " +
    "where id = new.id ; " +
    "end"
const val NEW_TRANSACTION_PARTY_TRIGGER_NAME = "transaction_insert_party_trigger"
const val NEW_TRANSACTION_PARTY_TRIGGER = "create trigger $NEW_TRANSACTION_PARTY_TRIGGER_NAME " +
    "after insert on transactions " +
    "begin " +
    "update transactions " +
    "set party_name = (select party.name from parties party where party.id = new.party_id) " +
    "where id = new.id ; " +
    "end"
```

As you can see from the snippet above, the table I am observing is named `transactions`. After any insertion in this table, I have to query the data from `parties` table to update the `firm_id` and `party_name` in this table itself, i.e the `transactions` table. Except, to my surprise, all I see is both the entries, `firm_id` and `party_name`, end up having the same value as `firm_id`. I am using the sqlite on android, hence I can't use `update-from` clause. I also tried single `trigger`, but that didn't work either. Looking forward to quick help, as I have my release on hold. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: The single trigger I had used before :
`create trigger if not exists $NEW_TRANSACTION_TRIGGER_NAME after insert on transactions begin update transactions set firm_id = (select firm_id from parties where id = new.party_id), party_name = (select name from parties where id = new.party_id) where id = new.id ; end`

Comment: Your 1st trigger updates firm_id and not firm_name, so does the single trigger. Do you have any other triggers? Post some sample data so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: My bad, it is the `firm_id` that I am trying to update. I will update the question with right text. Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I haven't tried it before. What is it exactly you need me to do here? I can do it with a little help.

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. In the link of my previous comment you can add sample data with CREATE and INSERT statements for the 2 tables so that we could reproduce the issue.

Comment: hmm, I see! is it possible that the sqlite version needs to older, like 3.8 for it to be reproducible?

Comment: For a version like 3.8 I'm afraid it could not be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify that to a single trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER whatever_name
AFTER INSERT ON transactions
BEGIN
 UPDATE transactions
 SET (firm_id, party_name) = (SELECT firm_id, name FROM parties WHERE parties.id = new.party_id)
 WHERE id = new.id;
END;
```

Works for me with a couple of quick sample tables and rows.

Comment: I wanted to use that, but I cant since android studio shows error for this syntax. Any idea which sqlite version started supporting this syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Since version 3.15.0 of SQLite

Comment: hmm, that explains the error then. cuz the apk has minimum sdk for android set to 16, which as per official documentation has sqlite version 3.7.x?